# How to dissolve metallic lead fast in nitric acid?

Tags: kinetics, solubility, lead

We were trying to dissolve a piece of metallic lead in concentrated nitric acid until we found out that concentrated nitric acid is not a suitable media, as long as it produces a layer of lead oxide which is harder to dissolve.

We tried then with nitric acid 1:4 in water and could notice a little advance in the digestion but it still looks like it is going to take a long time...

Does anyone have struggled with this before?

**Edit: It dissolved overnight. Sorry for being that impatient and thank you for all the help.**

Comment: Powder it, maybe?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I think it would be problematic since it is a relatively expensive certified reference material for isotopic composition (produced in 1991, the certificate does not contain a section for handling instructions), and would like to manipulate it the minimum possible

Comment: How about *hot* nitric acid?

Comment: Use pure nitric acid maybe?

Comment: Using subdestilled nitric acid was our first option but it forms a layer of PbO which does not allow the reaction with the acid to proceed anymore :(

Comment: Do you have an ultrasonic bath?

Comment: @Waylander I do have and will try it today. Thanks!

Comment: For your future reference look up https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lead(II)_nitrate. In the Chemical Properties and Reactions section they show the solubility of lead nitrate in nitric acid solutions, which decreases strongly with acid concentration. It's due to the common ion effect, which is significant because the concentration of nitrate ions from your 1:4 diluted nitric acid solution is comparable with that of the saturated water solution of the lead salt.

Comment: You are right, thank you. I should have done some search first before just attempting to get it into solution by brute force.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some ideas are given by [Bell[1]](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ac60335a027). The author recommends:

> Experiments in this laboratory have shown that mixtures of fluoroboric acid, hydrogen peroxide, and ethylenediaminetetraacetic acid (EDTA) rapidly dissolve lead alloys at room temperature. The addition of EDTA is necessary to prevent the formation of insoluble salts during the dissolution step.

**Understanding, and optimizing, nitric acid**

Nitric acid performs relatively poorly because the lead nitrate (not any oxide) produced by the reaction  has more limited solubility in nitric acid solution than in plain water. This is due to the common ion effect, and also at high concentration to nitric acid being a poorer solvating agent for ions than plain water (as distinct from its power as a reactant).

It follows that to maximize the solubility the acid should indeed be diluted with water. Using lead nitrate solubility data from [Ferris[2]](https://doi.org/10.1021/je60007a002) and the stoichiometry of the reaction between lead and nitric acid, the salt solubility is limited by the acid if the initial acid (before it reacts) is 21-23 weight% $\ce{HNO3}$ or more, depending slightly on whether the acid is reduced to $\ce{NO}$ or $\ce{NO2}$. With a more dilute acid, including the 1:4 diluted mixture that was actually used, saturation is avoided and the reaction proceeds until either the metal or the acid is exhausted.

**References**

1.
Harry F. Bell (1973). "Rapid dissolution technique for lead alloys". *Anal. Chem.*, **45**, 13, 2296–2297. https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ac60335a027.

2.
L. M. Ferris (1960). "Lead nitrate-nitric acid-water system". *J. Chem. Eng. Data*, **5**(3), 242. https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ac60335a027.